# How do I access the UI elements within an ItemsControl?

Tags: silverlight, itemscontrol

I have subclassed a Silverlight `ItemsControl` into a `SlideShow` control.  This works fine when I hard-code the item elements in the XAML directly.  But if I use a `DataTemplate`, how do I access the UI elements for each item?

Comment: why do you need to?  what do you need to do that you can't do in the datatemplate?

Comment: The `SlideShow` control runs animation storyboards against the items in the `ItemsControl` to fade-in and fade-out each control in turn. It does this in the tick of a `DispatcherTimer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ItemsControl may create new items for them as items come and go, so you have to use `ItemsControl.Items` to get each data item, then use `ItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem` (or other methods on the `ItemContainerGenerator` to find the UI element for that item that was created by the `DataTemplate`

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: I'm not using WPF, but I think this might still help.

Comment: the link is for the Silverlight version of those things.  I was using the word WPF in the *generic* sense of "ui object".

Comment: Is there an event I can hook when the item containers become available?

Comment: I seen ItemsChanged event, but I don't see anything for generation.  You might have to watch some other event on the ItemsControl for that?

Answer (score 0):

Parse through it with a foreach statement?

eg:

foreach (ChildObject c in ParentObject.Children)

Comment: I know how to foreach over a sequence. What I'm trying to figure out is what is "Children".